# From Static to dynamic linking on Solaris 10

Tags: linker, solaris, static-libraries, dynamic-linking, sun

Apparently Solaris 10 does not support static linking anymore. Therefore, I am wondering if anyone can assist me rewriting the makefile so that it supports dynamic linking. Essentially,
the following linker command gives me an error message that _memset is not found. Memset itself is in the standard library which should NOT be linked statically. Here is the linker command:

/usr/ccs/bin/ld -o q -e start_master -dn -z defs -M ../../../mapfile.q {list of object files}

Anyone an idea how I can get this running on Solaris 10 now?

Thanks!

Comment: The underlying assumption here is incorrect.   Solaris certainly supports static linking to any static library you have - many commands are built that way.   What Solaris 10 and later do not support is static linking to the system libraries - there simply is no libc.a nor other static system library provided.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
/usr/ccs/bin/ld -o q -e start_master -Bstatic -z defs -M ../../../mapfile.q {list of object files} -Bdynamic -lc
```